# Invoke a Mule flow from a java class - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mule

I want to invoke a mule flow from a java class(the flow already listens to VM endpoint) which I can do it from the creating a mule client as below :-

```
MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
client.dispatch("myEndPoint", "Message Payload", null);
```

However, I create the mule context while application start, i.e Spring Boot main method.

> How can I pass the mule context to any java class so that the method
>   that can be used to send message by creating a mule client as shown
>   above?

Answer (score 0):

Please reference the below blog which explains how to do this: 
http://bushorn.com/running-mule-from-java/

HTH

Comment: Yes, I can do that as shown in question but I dont want to load context every time my java class is executed

Comment: I think you expected to create component configuration(like db connection) using that each time you can get you mule client.In that case it will load context when it starts app only